# The combinatorics of $(f \partial)^n$ in the noncommutative setting?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, noncommutative-algebra, differential-algebra

This is a noncommutative version of these three previous questions:

[differential operator power coefficients](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80828/differential-operator-power-coefficients)

[Сlosed formula for $(g\partial)^n$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337330/%D0%A1losed-formula-for-g-partialn)

[A Leibniz-like formula for $(f(x) \frac{d}{dx})^n f(x)$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415617/a-leibniz-like-formula-for-fx-fracddxn-fx)

Let $(R,\partial)$ be a noncommutative differential ring (unitality does not play a role), i.e.
we have $\forall a,b \in R$:
$$
\partial (ab) = \partial(a) b + a \partial (b).
$$
Fix a generic element ("regular function") $f \in R$. I am interested in an explicit description of the iterations
$$
(R_f \partial)^n f,\ n \in \mathbb{N},
$$
where $R_f$ denotes the multiplication operator by $f$ *from the right*. For example:
$$
(R_f \partial) f = \partial(f) f
$$
and
$$
(R_f \partial)^2 f = (R_f \partial) (\partial(f) f) = \partial^2(f) f^2 + \partial(f)^2 f
$$
My question is thus:

> Is there a known explicit description for the words made out of the letters $\partial^n(f),\dotsc,\partial(f),f$ involved in the expansion of $(R_f \partial)^n f$ and the coefficients in front of these words? Has this been investigated anywhere?

Ideally, I am looking for a description similar to Comtet's theorem in the commutative case cited by [Gjergji Zaimi](https://mathoverflow.net/a/80873) in [the first link mentioned above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80828/differential-operator-power-coefficients).

**Aside:** My setting is actually slightly more complicated than this. I only have a derivation "with a twist":
$$
\partial (ab) = \partial(a) \varphi(b) + a \partial(b),
$$
where $\varphi$ is an (injective, non-unital) ring endomorphism with $[\varphi,\partial]$ not being very illuminating, which only seems to complicate the combinatorics even further.

Comment: Gjergji's answer contains a link to a paper with generalizations to the noncommutative case (I did not check what they are).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, Comtet's formula works almost directly in noncommutative case under an appropriate ordering of the products. Here is just a bit deeper look under the hood.

In umbral form $(R_f \partial)^n f$ can be written as polynomial
$$f_n(x_1,\dots,x_n) := x_1(x_1+x_2)(x_1+x_2+x_3)\cdots(x_1+\dots+x_n),$$
where in the expansion of $f_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ each monomial $x_1^{a_1}x_2^{a_2}\cdots x_n^{a_n}$ corresponds to
$(\partial^{a_1}f)(\partial^{a_2}f)\cdots(\partial^{a_n}f)f$.

The coefficient of $x_1^{a_1}x_2^{a_2}\cdots x_n^{a_n}$ in $f_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is nonzero only if the exponents satisfy the inequalities
$$a_n + a_{n-1} + \dots + a_{n-k+1} \leq k,\qquad k\in\{1,2,\dots,n-1\},$$
with the total degree being $n$:
$$a_n + a_{n-1} + \dots + a_1 = n,$$
in which case this coefficient is given by the formula:
\begin{split}
&\binom{1}{a_n}\binom{2-a_n}{a_{n-1}}\binom{3-a_n-a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}}\cdots \binom{n-a_n-a_{n-1}-\dots-a_2}{a_1} \\
&=\frac{(2-a_n)(3-a_n-a_{n-1})\cdots (n-a_n-a_{n-1}-\dots-a_2)}{a_1!a_2!\cdots a_n!}.
\end{split}

---

PS. It's worth to notice connection of $f_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ to other combinatorial objects, such as $q$-factorial (for $x_i=q^{i-1}$) and the generating function for Stirling numbers of first kind (for $x_2=\dots=x_n=1$).

Comment: Dear @Max Alekseyev, thank you very much for taking the time to write this down. I am not a combinatorialist, so I very much appreciate this. Do you know any good reference for the umbral methods you just employed, suitable for non-combinatorialists?

Comment: @M.G.: This problem does not require any advanced methods: connection with $f_n$ can be easily proved by induction on $n$, while the formula for the coefficients is computed "backwards" - first picking $a_n$ parentheses containing $x_n$ from the product, then $a_{n-1}$ parentheses containing $x_{n-1}$ etc. Given that the formula works well in noncommutative case, I'd not be surprised if Comtet mentioned that in his paper (but I did not check).