# Differential operator simplification

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-operators, orthogonal-polynomials

Does anyone know the explicit formulation for the $q_k$'s in, $$(x+D)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n q_k(x)D^k\ \ \ \ ?$$

I know that $e^{-x^2/2+x}$ is a fixed point of $(x+D)$. I also, know that $$(x+D)H_n(x)e^{-x^2/2} = 2n H_{n-1}(x)e^{-x^2/2},$$ where $H_n(x)$ are the Hermite polynomials. Hence, $$(x+D)^n H_k(x)e^{-x^2/2} = 0$$ for all $k<n$. However, this knowledge hasn't proven useful yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Updated Jan. 2 and 3, 2022)

I had forgotten this question by the time I wrote up last year in OEIS [A344678](https://oeis.org/A344678) a fairly complete characterization of the coefficients of the normal-ordering of the powers of $R = x+D$, the raising op for a family of Hermite polynomials.

For those interested in disentangling operators in general, see the ref in my initial answer below and also "[Evolution operator equations: integration with algebraic and finite difference methods. Applications to physical problems in classical and quantum mechanics and quantum field theory](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226801341_Evolution_operator_equations_Integration_with_algebraic_and_finitedifference_methods_Applications_to_physical_problems_in_classical_and_quantum_mechanics_and_quantum_field_theory)" by Dattoli, Ottaviabi, Torre, and Vasquez.

Re-ordering of iterated differential ops in terms of summands of the form $x^pD_x^q$ or $x^q(xD)^p$  gives rise to many classical special functions/sequences of polynomials important in combinatorics, analysis, and mathematical physics, e.g., the confluent hypergeometric polynomials, encompassing Hermite, Laguerre, Lah, and generalized Laguerre polynomials, associated with $(D_xx)^n$, $(xD_xx)^n = x^nD_x^nx^n$, $x^{-\alpha}(xD_xx)^nx^{\alpha}$ and $\binom{xD_x +\alpha+\beta}{\beta}$ (see this [MO-Q)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107159/pochhammer-symbol-of-a-differential-and-hypergeometric-polynomials/107191#107191); the Bell/Touchard/exponential/Stirling polynomials of the second kind, with $(xD_x)^n$; and the Stirling polynomials of the first kind and the generalized 'factorial' or generalized Witt polynomials related to $(x^rD_x)^n$ (see [A094638](https://oeis.org/A094638)).

There are numerous other OEIS entries linked to normal reordering, several related to this [MSE-Q](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116633/is-there-a-formula-similar-to-fxa-ea-fracddxfx-to-express-f-al). A hub OEIS entry for iterated Lie derivatives $(g(x)D_x)^n$ is [A145271](https://oeis.org/A145271) with several refs.
[This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97512/in-splendid-isolation/257205#257205) and [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97512/in-splendid-isolation/98213#98213) to the MO-Q "In 'Splendid Isolation'" allude to related work, neglected in most accounts, by Charles Graves (and by Pincherle) on the commutator/operator derivatives  $[f(L),R] = f'(L)$ and $[L,f(R)] = f'(R)$, where $L$ and $R$ are lowering/annihilation/destruction and raising/creation ladder ops, and the flow equation $\exp[tg(x)D_x] W(x) = W[f^{(-1)}(f(x)+t)]$ where $g(x) = 1/f'(x)$.

Initial post (Jun, 2014):

See "[Combinatorial models of creation-annihilation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.0354)" by Blasiak and Flajolet.

Comment: Great resource! Proposition 2 is exactly my problem, but more than that is a database of differential operator manipulations. Thanks.

Comment: The second link (to Dattoli et al.) seems broken - I wonder can it be fixed?

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt,  Oops. Fixed.

Comment: Three additional refs created after 2014: the book Commutation Relations,
Normal Ordering, and Stirling Numbers by Mansour and Schork (2015) and the survey paper "Recent developments in combinatorial aspects of normal ordering" by Schork (2021). There are some related notes on a generalized creation op at "A Creation Op, Scaled Flows, and Operator Identities" (2022) (https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2022/02/02/a-creation-op/).

Comment: See also my later posts (2022) “Dualities Between the Appell Raising Op and the Generalized Creation Op” (https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2022/02/07/dualities-between-the-appell-raising-op-and-the-generalized-creation-op/ and “Stirling Raisings:
Creation Ops for the Faa di Bruno-Bell Polynomials” (https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2022/02/10/raising-stirling/).