# Have you seen this Lie algebra?

Tags: lie-algebras, lie-algebra-cohomology, virasoro-algebra

Computing something I have come across a Lie algebra $\def\L{\mathfrak L}\def\CC{\mathbb C}\L_N$ that I would like to identify.

Fix an integer $N$ such that $N\geq2$, let $\L_N$ be the free complex vector space over the set $\{e_{l}:l\geq-N+1\}$, and turn $\L_N$ into a Lie algebra setting
$$
  [e_l, e_m] =
    \begin{cases}
    0 & \text{if $i+u>N$} \\
      & \text{or $l+m<-N+1$;} \\
    \dfrac{l(v+1)-m(j+1)}{N-1}\cdot e_{l+m} & \text{othewise.}
    \end{cases}
  $$
where $j$ and $v$ are the quotients of dividing $l$ and $m$ by $N-1$, respectively.

> **Question.** What is this algebra?

When $N=2$ this is isomorphic to the algebra $W_1=\operatorname{Der}(\mathbb C[t])$ of vector fields on the line, with $e_l$ corresponding to $-t^{l+1}\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t}$ and, in fact, for all $N$ the subspace $\L_N^0$ spanned by $\{e_{j(N-1)}:j\geq-1\}$ is a subalgebra isomorphic to $W_1$.

In that spirit, one can look at the Lie algebra (I'll hack the notation for Lie algebras of vector fields…)
$$
  W_{1/(N-1)} = \left\langle -t^{\frac{l}{N-1}+1}\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t}:l\geq-N+1\right\rangle
  $$
which has brackets
$$
  \left[
  -t^{\frac{l}{N-1}+1}\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t}
  ,
  -t^{\frac{m}{N-1}+1}\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t}
  \right]
  = \frac{l-m}{N-1} 
    \left(-t^{\frac{l+m}{N-1}+1}\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t}\right).
  $$
This has an *air de famille* with $\L_N$, of course, but it is not quite it. In any case, this gives a reason not to renormalize the denominator away in the formula for the bracket of $\L_N$.

The difference between $\L_N$ and $W_{1/(N-1)}$ is in the behaviour $\mod N-1$ of the indices of course. One can try loopifying $W_1$ into $W_1\otimes\CC[t]/(t^N)$, but that's something very different, or even something like a twisted loop algebra $W_1\ltimes\CC[t]/(t^N)$, with $W_1$ acting on the second factor by derivations, but this does not give anything extra because $W_1$ is simple and cannot act in many ways. It could be that one needs to further deform the $\CC[t]/(t^N)$-loop algebra along a cocycle.

The algebra $\L_N$ has a unique maximal nilpotent ideal $\def\N{\mathfrak{N}}\N$ , spanned by the $e_l$ with $l$ not divisible by $N-1$, which has index exactly $N-1$. The quotient $\L_N/\N$ is a copy of $W_1$, the extension is in fact split and the action of $W_1$ on $\N$ is semisimple — a direct sum of modules in the so called «intermediate series» for $W_1$, which look like $\CC[t]t^\alpha(dt)^\beta$ (these are «$\beta$-density bundles» that come with a flat connection, so an action of the first Weyl algebra and, by restriction, one of $W_1$) for $N-2$ pairs $(\alpha,\beta)$ that one can compute.

Comment: $\mathbb C[t]/(t^N)$-loop algebra sounds very wrong: it should be  something like infinitessimal path algebra, if we look at things like $\mathfrak{g}\otimes\mathbb C[t]$ as path algebras, in analogy of $\mathfrak{g}\otimes\mathbb C[t^{\pm1}]$ being loop algebras.

Comment: Maybe you can find some leads in the refs to https://oeis.org/A094638. Note my Nov. 02, 2010, comment.

Comment: @TomCopeland, I was wondering how to attract your attention to this question and it seems telepathy works better than any messaging system :-)

Comment: All you need do is paint the $x^{\alpha} D$ operator on a spotlight and ... . // Sorry that I don't have a deeper knowledge of such an algebra and am awaiting to see some answers from others.

Comment: See also "Recent developments in combinatorial aspects of normal ordering" by Matthias Schork.

Comment: Note also, with $t = x^{N-1}$,

$t^{\frac{m+N-1}{N-1}}\frac{d}{dt} = \frac{1}{N-1} x^{m+1}\frac{d}{dx}$, and you have a scaled Witt algebra.

Comment: Btw, in my pdf at "Infinigens, the Pascal Triangle, and the Witt and Virasoro Algebras" (https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2012/11/29/infinigens-the-pascal-pyramid-and-the-witt-and-virasoro-algebras/), I give another rep of the Witt algebra à la Givental and relate it to the Laguerre polynomials of order -1/2, connected with one family of the Hermite polynomials. (Just search on Witt in the pdf.)

Comment: For more on ops of the form $(x^{m+1}D)^n$, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/172899/differential-operator-simplification/172900#172900.

Comment: Regarding my earlier comment, the local Lie group action of the op $\exp[\alpha \frac{1}{N-1} x^{m+1}\frac{d}{dx} ]$ is the same as $\exp[\beta  x^{m+1}\frac{d}{dx}]$ with $\beta = \alpha/(N-1)$. See my MO-A to "Motivation of Virasoro algebra" (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117287/motivation-of-virasoro-algebra).